# What is the best way to retry downloading continuously till it is finished regardless of internet connection state in VCS winform app?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, download

I am developing a winform app in VCS. In that app, I am downloading some online files having static URL. Sometimes it is aborting due to poor internet connection in some cases. I am wondering what is the best way so that my app will retry endlessly untill the downloading is successfully completed. I have thought of the following but not sure whether this is the best approach or not:

```
DOWNLOADING:

try
{
    //Downloading code
}

catch
{
    goto DOWNLOADING;
}
```

If it is not the best approach, what is the best way?

Comment: You're looking for a loop.

Comment: @SLaks I assume you mean some sort of loop on worker thread or maybe even loop with `await` inside? (Also if `goto` is suggested as close competitor for "the best approach" such minor issues like frozen UI should not be of concern).

Comment: No; I mean a simple `while` loop (although you don't want to block the UI thread either)